# Filebeat to Kafka Connection over SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, filebeat

I have a secure Kafka server. I'm able to connect (producer/consumer) to the Kafka using the client truststore jks.

Using Filebeat I want to write data to this Kafka server where output.kafka.ssl does not have options for jks.

I have tried converting the `kafka.client.truststore.jks` to cer.pem and key.pem, but the key.pem is empty after the conversion.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filebeat uses golang, so a Java keystore file wouldn't help. Please show how you converted the file. Have you tried using the file, even if it's empty?

Comment: I have followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40194333/5804494 for converting the keystore to pem files.

Comment: Which way? keytool -exportcert?

Comment: No the above method of keytool -exportcert, converting to PKCS12 one