# KAFKA Python SSL Certificate

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, consumer

I am working on Python script on Windows 10 to connect to consume KAFKA topic. The SSL certificate is installed on Windows server in .jks format. The SSL connection to KAFKA is possible only with his certificate.

I wanted to know if there is a way I can tell Python to get the default certificate from the specific location? Will Python accept .jks format certificate? If not then what options I have.

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't Java. JKS files really only work within the context of a JVM

You can use `keytool` commands to export a PEM certificate from a JKS file to be used for non Java purposes

[How to convert trust certificate from .jks to .pem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24343681/2308683)